# Sorting records starting with upper and lower case in Laravel view

Tags: php, sorting, laravel, laravel-5.1

When sorting records in Blade template all records beginning with lower case letter appear at the bottom. How do I force sortBy to list all records alphabetically?

```
@foreach ($registrations->sortBy('profile_last_name') as $registration)
  record list
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [natcasesort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.natcasesort.php)

```
@foreach (natcasesort($registration->last_name) as $last_name)
  record list
@endforeach
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have provided a better example. Edited my question. How would I apply natcasesort() in this scenario.

Comment: Are you providing the correct key for which you want to sort it alphabetically? Coz `sortBy` already sorts it in asc order for the provided key.

Comment: Yes, it sorts it alphabetically but all upper case first and all lower case second, so I end up with something like this:

First, 
Third, 
second.

Comment: `natcasesort` returns a boolean. How can you traverse a boolean?